# Unable to access server on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I recently set up a provisioning account for my iOS device for my Xamarin project.

The app launches fine and shows to first screen well, but when I attempt to perform an action like `Logging in` which requires hitting a local database I have in the office, I get **nothing** on the console output on my server I am hitting (I'm never reaching the server from my app). My code works fine (hits the server and provides output) when running on the `iOS simulator`, the `Android simulator` and a `physical android device`.

I believe this is probably a simple setting, or something of the like (some type of permission for iOS devices?) but I'm not sure where exactly my problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. My device was not connected to my office's WIFI so I was unable to hit the server. Leaving this posted incase anyone makes the same mistake as me in the future!